# How can I connect to database using FXRuby

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, fxruby

I'd like to create an app that accesses db (with 1 table) and outputs its table in a window **using FXRuby**. Is there any way to make it **without using query language** like in this example:

```
require 'pg'

conn = PG.connect(dbname: 'testdb', user: 'postgres')    
rows = conn.exec("select * from users")
```

And **without using Ruby on Rails**.

I've also tried to launch this example code, but it doesn't work beacause of the problem with installing `sqlite3 gem`:

```
require 'fox16' 
require 'sqlite3.rb' 
include Fox 

class TestApp < FXApp 
   def initialize 
      super('Test', 'Test') 
      @db = SQLite3::Database.new('test.db3') 
      @db || raise("can't connect to database") 
   end 

   def db 
      @db 
   end 
end
```

Comment: What do you mean "without using query language"?  You're going to have use *some* sort of query to access the database.  Incidentally, I use `fox16` and the `sqlite3` gems all the time in my applications, so what *exactly* is the problem installing the `sqlite3` gem?

Comment: @varro I'm using win 10 + ruby 2.5.3 and when I try to "gem install sqlite3"  it fails.

Comment: You should try to be as explicit as possible in your error reports, but I will guess that here that you do not have your development environment set up correctly.  The fox16 gem is a C/C++ extension, which means you will need to compile it.  Do you have a compiler installed?  And what is your development environment?

Comment: @varro I've installed ruby interpreter from rubyinstaller.org/ and use powershell to launch code.

Comment: But do you have a *compiler*?  I use MSYS myself as a development environment, but going to the rubyinstaller website, it looks like you can install MSYS2/DevKit under Add-ons.  Do you have that?

Comment: @varro yes, it's installed, but not that sqlite3 gem

Comment: Just to double-check, if you run the command `gem list`, do you see a line for "fxruby" but *not* for "sqlite3"?  And when you run `gem install sqlite3`, what is the *exact* error message you see?  (Just saying "it fails" is not *nearly* good enough.)

Comment: @varro since the first time I've tried to 'gem install sqlite3' it returns:"... checking for -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options...".

Comment: @varro I've googled this problem but it only has a solution for ruby-on-rails with changing sqlite3 source in Gemfile

Comment: oh. seems like fxruby was left behind a long time ago... :(

Comment: Um... what does that mean exactly?  Does that mean you have neither the fxruby or the sqlite3 gems installed?  As I said, I've been using both for years.

Comment: @varro fxruby gem is working fine, but I can't use sqlite3 gem, because of that error "... missing function dlopen ..."

Comment: @varro ann attempt to get sqlite3 gem https://i.imgur.com/IxTZwbb.png

Comment: The next thing to do is look up that "mkmf.log" file cited in the primary error message and scan it for more details.

Comment: @varro I appreciate your help! So many times you've answered me already, but I don't know what to do with this file, it's large enough and there's no way to find this problem in the net. (the pdf of mkmf:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1REZqnX2-XDf07retbEOW0vOHamiATU82/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following should solve your problem (see [this reference](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/248)):

```
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn
gem install sqlite3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I should have googled my error message in the proper way